# UIImage Scale Aspect Fill and Clip Subviews not working in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a cell containing a single UIImageView. I'm setting the UIImageView frame.size to match the cell's frame.size and also explicitly asking the UIImageView to Scale with Aspect Fill & Clip Subview the following way in ***cellForItemAtIndexPath*** method:

```
let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

... 

var imageView = UIImageView(image: self.eventImages[indexPath.row])
imageView.frame.size = cell.frame.size
cell.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
cell.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
cell.addSubview(imageView)
```

The result is a stretched out image **(IMAGE A)**, but when I click (tap) the image it "magically" resolves the Aspect Fill & Clip Subviews **(IMAGE B)** . I can't seem to understand why this is happening only after a tap and not when loading the images for the first time. They are fetched asynchronously to a server, but the scaling only occurs after a tap of the image (there is also no tap functionality implemented).

NOTE: The UICollectionView is set up in a storyboard View Controller, both the Collection View and the Reusable Cell have Aspect Fill and Clip Subviews enabled.

### **IMAGE A (wrong scaling - stretched out and no cropping):**

[image: IMG A]

### **IMAGE B (correct scaling after tap):**

[image: IMG B]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is very simple just do this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: should be imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: what else do you see, I wrote?

Comment: Swift 4 = `imageView.layer.maskToBounds = true`

Comment: In my case, it worked when I have set width and height constraints.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should be using:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

instead of this:

```
  cell.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
  cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Nope, had both but also just tried commenting the cell scaling and leaving only the imageView scaling but didn't work. In the **storyboard** both the Collection View and the Collection Reusable Cell have `Aspect Fill` and `Clip Subviews`... Any recomendations on something different that might work in there?

Comment: In my case, it worked when I have set width and height constraints.

Answer (score 1):

[yourImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
 yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score -1):

imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true